# Error502: "Internal server error" in Amplify

Tags: aws-amplify, http-status-code-502

I'm trying to get checkout session of stripe  in Amplify.
I created Amplify rest api and function with path already.
So I changed app.js in amplify/backend/function/stripeAPI/src.

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const awsServerlessExpressMiddleware = require('aws-serverless-express/middleware')

// declare a new express app
const app = express()
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_****************************WK');
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(awsServerlessExpressMiddleware.eventContext())

// Enable CORS for all methods
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
  next()
});


/**********************
 * Example get method *
 **********************/

app.get('/checkout', async function(req, res) {
  try {
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(req.query.session_id);
    const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(session.customer);
    res.json({success: true, url: req.url, customer: customer});    
  } catch (error) {
    res.json({error: error.message});
  }
});


app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("App started")
});

// Export the app object. When executing the application local this does nothing. However,
// to port it to AWS Lambda we will create a wrapper around that will load the app from
// this file
module.exports = app
```

I tested in postman, but got error 502.